# How do you pass a type as a parameter in c++?

Tags: c++, function-parameter

I want to pass a type as a parameter (not a variable or a reference).

I have this working code:

execution code where "testState2" is the name of a class (i.e. the type in this case). **Note** it has a base type of state_t:

```
changeState(new testState2());
```

change state function:

```
void state_t::changeState(state_t * new_state)
{
    // Check if the state has changed
    if (this != new_state)
    {
        qDebug() << this->name << ": State changed to: " << new_state->name;
        delete this;
        _state = new_state;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << this->name << ": State un-changed";
    }
}
```

In this code I am basically creating a new instance of testState2, but I want to simplify the calling code further. I want to just pass in the type, like this:

```
    changeState(testState2);
```

Note: There is no "new" and this is not creating an instance, merely passing the name of the class, so:

1. Is this even possible?
2. If so, how?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. using templates.

Comment: `delete this; state = new_state;`? Gosh no, please please please tell me that `_state` is not a data member of the current class.

Comment: If testState2 is inherited from state_t the code should just work as long as you are treating it as a state_t

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, I looked at templates but you still appear to need a variable name `template <class T> myType GetMax (T input)` I only want to pass in T, can you provide the syntax for this?

Comment: Yeah, and you definitely don't want `delete this;`.  I think your on the wrong track with the way your trying to solve your problem...

Comment: As you cannot pass "types" as arguments, you can pass objects that know the type of the object you want to create, and invoke a construction method on these objects. This is a Factory pattern.

Comment: `delete this;` What is this I don't even...

Comment: You could pass a factory function, if you want to specify what type to create at runtime, but I agree with the other posts that you need to re-consider whether you actually want to do this.

Comment: That delete this followed by any code altering the deleted class is a no go - please read a book (mmm does any book explain that !?)

Comment: ok, it appears I have gone wrong somewhere along the way - this is experimental code for a statemachine I am trying this new (to me) method of having a class for each state of my state machine. Probably its best that I close this question and make a new one to get help on what I should be doing! thanks for the feedback.

Comment: This question seems to imply that you are attempting to treat your states as objects instead of as valid values of an object.  To put that in other terms:  it would be like declaring a class `1` for an integer with the value of 1, and another class `2` for an integer with the value of 2, instead of declaring a class `Integer` that can hold any integer value.  Where you are going is likely going to make your design almost impossible to do anything useful (especially if you are trying to simulate a state machine).

Comment: Don't implement the state machine *inside* the states. Make the machine a separate class that handles transitions.

Comment: @code_fodder You might be interested to have a look at [STTCL](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/).

Comment: @g-makulik & molbdnilo ah, crap.... I just went off and wrote another question :o ... I will indeed look at these links though, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes (and types in general) in C++ are not first-class values and therefore cannot be passed around or stored.

For classes you can theoretically use `typeid` but most often I found more useful just having strings returned by a virtual function in instances and a registry to implement a "virtual constructor" pattern.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual const char *class_name() = 0;
    ...
};

struct MyClass : public(Base)
{
    virtual const char *class_name() { return "MyClass"; }
    ...
}

std::map<std::string, Base *(*)()> instance_builders;
```

Answer (score 0):

For learning the State pattern, the example at
[State Design Pattern in C++](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/cpp/1) may be a good starting point.